# Как будет выглядеть запрос в mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Есть объекты такого вида у которых могут быть **entityType** разные.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5fc87d023fb22414289927ef"),
  "projectId" : "5fb3a11e3fb2242284fe6611",
  "description" : "",
  "entityType" : "DEVICE",
  "entityId" : "5fb3a1293fb2242284fe6615",
  "level" : "WARNING",
}
```

Я хочу удалить все объекты, в запросе передавать карту из **entityType** и список **entityId** Как можно это сделать?

Так будет выглядит запрос, если я буду передавать конкретный тип и массив

```
({$and:[{"projectId": "5fb3a11e3fb2242284fe6611"}, {"entityType" : "DEVICE"}, {"entityId": {$in: ["5fb3a1293fb2242284fe6615", "5fb3a1293fb2242284fe661f"]}} ]})
```

То есть: Имеется такие параметры

```
projectId, 
Object = {
entityType1: [arrayIds], 
entityType2: [arrayIds],  
entityType3: [arrayIds]
}
```

Comment: опишите условие словами

Comment: @Дмытрык если совпадает projectId и Object[entityType] содержит в себе entityId
Не знаю, честно говоря даже как описать...

Comment: @Дмытрык если описать в JS, то будет как 

projectId === projectId && object[DEVICE].includes(entityId)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, понял ли правильно, но попробуйте так:
`db.collection.deleteOne({_id:ObjectId("5fc87d023fb22414289927ef"), entityId: {$elemMatch:{$eq:{'5fb3a1293fb2242284fe6615'}}})`

entityId - должен быть массивом